# mod_rewrite directory path to deeper directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I don't usually work with LAMP and am a bit stumped getting a site working locally.

The site is set up to be used via localhost:

```
1) http://localhost/mysite
```

However, the way the site files are physically on the server the root is located as such:

```
2) /var/www/mysite/trunk/site
```

I'm trying to figure out a way where I could type #1 but have apache actually looking for the files in #2 so that all of the asset/page links in the web application work.

Is mod_rewrite the solution?

If so, I'm stumped on the syntax. I have this but it won't work (due, I assume, to it causing an infinite loop)

```
RewriteRule ^mysite/ mysite/trunk/site
```

I have a hunch I need to sprinkle on some regex?

UPDATE:

Per badman's suggestion, I now placed this in my htaccess file:

```
Alias /mysite /mysite/trunk/site
```

I've also tried this:

```
Alias /mysite /var/www/mysite/trunk/site
```

I end up in my server logs with this error:

```
[alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/.htaccess: Alias not allowed here
```

So, clearly I'm putting this in the wrong spot. You'd think this would be something I could easily google, but oddly I can't find an example that shows me WHERE that line should live on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting something like this in your VirtualHost configuration or into the server configuration:

```
 Alias /mysite /var/www/mysite/trunk/site
```

Once you point your alias there, be sure to create a  entry for /var/www/mysite/trunk/site.  More information on aliasing in Apache can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

Comment: likely dumb question: do I put that line in my .htaccess file?

Comment: No, it cannot be put in an .htaccess file.  If you follow the link and look up the Alias directive, you will see that its context is server config or VirtualHost.  Do you have access to change either of those configurations?

Comment: @Badman...this is all on my local Ubuntu VM, so I can change whatever. I'm just a bit lost...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu's Apache set-up, but can try to help.  What needs to be clarified?

Comment: I'm not sure which file that 'alias' line should be placed in.

Comment: After a bit of reading online, have a look at the config files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/.  These files contain the definitions for each site that your Apache installation will host.  At the very least there should be a file "default."  Edit that file, and put the Alias line and the Directory entry in that file.  Restart Apache and all should be well.  I referenced this site:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP as well as the link in my answer above.